# Set entity's UpdatedAt property when using EF Core and DDD

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-core-2.2

My entity has this:

```
public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; private set; }
```

I want to update that property every time I update the entity, so I have this:

```
private void updateTimeStamp() => UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

But then I need to remember to call it in every method that mutates the entity, e.g.:

```
public void addOrder(Order order) {
  //blah blah
  updateTimeStamp();     // <----- musn't forget this!
}
```

I often forget to call that method, so I'm thinking of alternatives. I don't know which is best, or if there's something I haven't considered.

**Option 1: intialise the property**

```
public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; private set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Problem: this would be set every time, even if I don't want to update the entity.

**Option 2: attributes**

```
[UpdateTimestamp]
public void addOrder(Order order) {
  //blah blah
}
```

Problem: this doesn't improve the situation, it's basically the same as the original problem.

**Option 3: automatic update in `context.SaveChanges()`**

```
ChangeTracker.Entries()
  .Where(e => e.Entity is MyEntity)
  .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified)
  .Where(e => e.Entity as MyEntity)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(e => { e.UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow; });
```

Problem: `UpdatedAt` now needs a public setter. This breaks DDD principles. This is the easiest option, but means I must give up DDD's "always valid".

**Option 3: same as 3 but using reflection**
Similar to option 3, I could use reflection to change the property even though it has a private setter. This is easy enough to do and the fact that it's reflection and "slow" is not a big deal as the time would be negligible in comparison to the database write.

Problem: making the change in the infrastructure rather than the domain, just feels wrong.

This is a pretty good choice otherwise. It's not pure DDD, but it at least allows me to protect the entity's invariants.

**Option 4: offload to db provider or db itself**

```
builder.Property(e => e.UpdatedAt).ValueGeneratedOnUpdate();
// or
builder.Property(e => e.UpdatedAt).HasComputedColumnSql("GETDATE()");
```

Problem: doesn't work for all providers (doesn't work for me because I'm using Npgsql which doesn't support computed columns). Also this moves the problem into the infrastructure and out of the domain. So I feel like I'm breaking DDD again.

*So... is there something I've forgotten? If you're doing DDD, how do you handle this?*

Comment: Why do you need a public setter?

Comment: Have you tried [Shadow Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties)

Comment: @Matthiee I know about shadow properties... but I'm not sure how would they help in this case?

Comment: But you can do `e.SetUpdatedAt()` for example instead and keep the property setter private.

Comment: @DavidG I'm not sure I follow your idea... however it's not just about whether the property setter is public or not, or whether I hide it behind a public method - the DDD matter here is that 1) it should not be possible for any code to change it, other than the entity itself, and 2) only when something **actually changed*.

Answer (score 1):

As you already pointed out option 1 does not fit as you could simply get an Order without updating anything and the date would change anyway.

Option 2 would probably also break DDD principles as you could have modified your Order and haven't changed your update date until you hit that particular method.

All you got left is option 3, I guess it's the less bad considering the DDD principles and also the most comfortable to use.
You should go this way. Simply create an interface with your UpdatedAt property and your updateTimeStamp method and implement it on your entities. You should probably create a base class and implement that method. Then get the modified entries in SaveChanges method as you suggested and use the method instead of the property to avoid setting the setter private.

There is a 4th option where you can use reflection and proxies classes but it would be a long shot for only what you ask...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've since option 4... what do you think is the "best" of the lot now? Agree with your idea about the `updateTimeStamp()` method to be called from the context, that's how I originally did it, but it feel so wrong (also it's not so different to just setting the property as public). The reflection idea I also considered, but seems like a round about way to get it done (I'm gonna add it to the list now). I think this is one of those cases where DDD becomes impractical! :(

Comment: If you really need to stick to the DDD principles, I guess that you have to create a private property for each of you properties, bound the public one to the private and call the update method inside the setter...
You should look how mvvm pattern binds properties, maybe you could find something that suits you there.
Finally, I think that you should not lock yourself in a single way of doing. Some design does not have a simple solution for one specific problem and you'll have to work a lot just trying to follow it. Sometimes it's ok to make concession for sake of simplicity and readability.

Comment: Agree about being practical.